# Clarify about extends throw and catch function in java

Tags: java

I have been taught as the THROW function will catch the value which got the nearest parent. As the code at below.

```
   package Lesson8.Practice;
   class Exc0 extends Exception{}
   class Exc1 extends Exc0{} 
   public class Test2 {
       public static void main(String[]args){
           try{
               throw new Exc1();
           }catch (Exc0 e0){
               System.out.println("Ex0 caught");
           }catch (Exception e){
               System.out.println("exception caught");
           }
       }
   }// output is ex0 caught
```

So I try to get the answer which is exception caught by edit the code as below

```
   package Lesson8.Practice;
   class Exception extends Exc0 {}
   class Exc1 extends Exception{} 
   public class Test2 {
       public static void main(String[]args){
           try{
               throw new Exc1();
           }catch (Exc0 e0){
               System.out.println("Ex0 caught");
           }catch (Exception e){
               System.out.println("exception caught");
           }
       }
   }// output is exception caught
```

So why the code is wrong

Comment: Your second code doesn't compile. Where is the declaration of `Exc0`?

Comment: that's all for the code I write, the exception also don't have any declaration why does it can be use

Comment: no, it isn't. you can't extend Exc0 if it doesn't exist. Also: why would that result be wrong?

Comment: Left over .class file from the first version?

Comment: @Stultuske the result of my second code? the write of the output is just an example to show what I want to find, but the whole code cannot be execute. So does it mean only the Exception can be extend even we didn't clarify it

Comment: @tgdavies sorry.. I not really know what you mean

Comment: I was speculating that perhaps the second version of your code compiled because there was an Exc0.class file left over from your first version. But as I think you're saying that the second version *doesn't* compile, don't worry about it.

Comment: What error messages do you get when you try to compile your second version? What do you think they mean? Which ones are you uncertain about?

Comment: @tgdavies ohhh, not I did the code separately

Comment: @tgdavies The question I want to know is the difference between class Exc0 extends Exception{}
and class Exception extends Exc0  {}, so Exc0 cannot be use because I didn't declare it, but I also didn't declared about the Exception so does it mean only 'Exception' don't need to declare and why

Comment: @tgdavies I get this
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Exc0

Comment: OK, why do you think that is? The reason that you didn't need to declare `Exception` is the same reason that you don't need to declare `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
package Lesson8.Practice;
class Exception extends Exc0 {}
```

you are declaring a >new< class called `Exception` in the `Lesson8.Practice` package.  Its full name will be `Lesson8.Practice.Exception`.

This will be different to the `java.lang.Exception` class that you used in the first version of the file; i.e. when you compiled this:

```
class Exc0 extends Exception{}
```

So ... you *probably* now have an exception type hierarchy this:

```
java.lang.Exception:
    Lesson8.Practice.Exc0:
        Lesson8.Practice.Exception:
            Lesson8.Practice.Exc1:
```

And the `Exception` in your `Test2` class will actually be referring to `Lesson8.Practice.Exception`

Note: if you were to delete all of the ".class" files that you have created by compiling different versions of the above, then recompile the latest version, you should find that you get a compilation error ... because `Exc0` is no longer declared.

---

Lessons:

#1 - You can't *change* the standard classes ... like `java.lang.Exception`.  Don't try.  You'll only run into confusing problems.

#2 - Don't reuse class names from the `java.lang` package for your own classes.  You can get yourself into an awful mess by doing that.

#3 - If things get really confused, you sometimes need to delete *all* of your ".class" files and then recompile everything.

Comment: May I confirm again haha, so from what you said just now, Exception can be extended by others if I got insert java.lang.Exception and also I may not prefer to create a class which the name of it is same as the java.lang package is it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know if I understand what you just asked there.  However 1) you can declare `SomeException extends java.lang.Exception {...}` and 2) you cannot declare `java.lang.Exception extends SomeException {...}`.  (You *might* be able to get a Java compiler to compile the latter, but there is no way that you will be able to use that redefined `Exception` class with any known JVM.)